# Java Selenium Webdriver no suitable method found for until

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I wrote a selenium script for work in Java. Suddenly the method `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someId")))` dosen't work. It worked before, but i can't remember a change, which did this error.
I didn't forget to initialize the wait var. I did it so: "`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100000);`".
My IDE says "Cannot resolve method 'until...'" when i move over the red underlined text.
When I try to run my main, these errors appears:

```
Error:(54, 13) java: cannot access com.google.common.base.Function
  class file for com.google.common.base.Function not found
Error:(82, 17) java: no suitable method found for until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>)
    method org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(com.google.common.base.Predicate<org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to com.google.common.base.Predicate<org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver>)
    method org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<V>until(com.google.common.base.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) V
        (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to com.google.common.base.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>))
```

Can somebody help?